# how to install speacific podfile in ios with out touching other podfiles

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I want to install specific dependency using cocoapods. if I execute pod install, other dependencies are updating before installing my newly added dependency. I just want to install specific pod without touching other dependencies. And I know deleting, updating any dependency also updates others. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Actually my problem is when I myself modify some dependency and run pod install it reverts back to its original version. But I don't want to lose my changes

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that **Podfile.lock** is in the same folder as **Podfile** is.

Add a line in the **Podfile**

```
pod 'MBProgressHUD','~> 0.9'
```

cd to your project and use the following line in the Terminal, it'll install just the above pod you specified.

```
pod install podName
```

From official website here's [the link](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html)!

> Running pod install will install the current version of RestKit, causing a Podfile.lock to be generated that indicates the exact version installed (e.g. RestKit 0.10.3). Thanks to the Podfile.lock, running pod install on this hypothetical project at a later point in time on a different machine will still install RestKit 0.10.3 even if a newer version is available. CocoaPods will honour the Pod version in Podfile.lock unless the dependency is updated in the Podfile or pod update is called (which will cause a new Podfile.lock to be generated). In this way CocoaPods avoids headaches caused by unexpected changes to dependencies.